# Powershell - Strange variable value return

Tags: powershell, return-value

I have a (for me) strange result with a script.
This is a summary of my script which returns the same result:

```
cls
$Init          = "AFFAIRES"
$ListeGroupes  = @() 
$NomGrScan     = "AFFAIRES"
$Grp0          = New-Object psobject
$Grp0          | Add-Member -Name "Nom"  -MemberType NoteProperty -value $Init
$Grp0          | Add-Member -Name "Scan" -MemberType NoteProperty -value "N"
$ListeGroupes += $Grp0 
$LGroupes1     = @()
$LGroupes1    += $ListeGroupes
write-host "Grp0 : $($Grp0.Nom) - $($Grp0.scan)"
write-host "ListeGroupes : $($ListeGroupes.Nom) - $($ListeGroupes.scan)"
write-host "LGroupes1 : $($LGroupes1.Nom) - $($LGroupes1.scan)"
($LGroupes1 | where {$_.nom -eq "$NomGrScan"}).scan = "O"
write-host "============================================="
write-host "Grp0 : $($Grp0.Nom) - $($Grp0.scan)"
write-host "ListeGroupes : $($ListeGroupes.Nom) - $($ListeGroupes.scan)"
write-host "LGroupes1 : $($LGroupes1.Nom) - $($LGroupes1.scan)"
```

When I run it on my computer I get:

```
Grp0 : AFFAIRES - N
ListeGroupes : AFFAIRES - N
LGroupes1 : AFFAIRES - N
=============================================
Grp0 : AFFAIRES - O
ListeGroupes : AFFAIRES - O
LGroupes1 : AFFAIRES - O
```

On line 15 of the script I only change the value of `$LGroupe1`. 
Why does it also change the values of `$ListeGroupe` and `$Grp0`?

I don't understand why I don't get:

```
Grp0 : AFFAIRES - N
ListeGroupes : AFFAIRES - N
LGroupes1 : AFFAIRES - N
=============================================
Grp0 : AFFAIRES - N
ListeGroupes : AFFAIRES - N
LGroupes1 : AFFAIRES - O
```

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell, objects (like the value in `$Grp0`) are treated as references. So, assigning a varible to an existing object gets you - not a new object - but another reference to the same object.

```
$a = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ prop1='a' ; prop2='b' }
$b = $a
```

`$b` points to the same object as `$a`. Changes to one affect the other.

One possible way to get around this is to use the `Copy()` method on `PSObject`.

```
$a = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ prop1='a' ; prop2='b' }
$b = $a.PSObject.Copy()
```

Now, `$a` and `$b` point to different objects and changes to one will not affect the other.

Note that `Copy()` only does a shallow copy.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.
Now I understand better.

Answer (score 0):

I came to try your code :

```
$a = New-Object PSObject -Property @{ prop1='a' ; prop2='b' }
$b = $a.Copy()
```

and i have this (sorry it's in french) :

```
Échec lors de l’appel de la méthode, car [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] ne contient pas de méthode nommée « Copy ».
_Failed to call the method, because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named "Copy"_
Au caractère Ligne:2 : 1
+ $b = $a.Copy()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation : (Copy:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound
```

Where is my mistake ?
thank you

Comment: Ooop! forgot the important qualifier on the Copy(). That line should be `$b = $a.PSObject.Copy()` Answer corrected.